# Apache - apply an htaccess directive to only one page?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

How do you apply an Apache deny directive to one specific page only in a directory?

Comment: you keep generating new accounts, perhaps because you are clearing cookies on every visit? You are damaging your ability to respond to your own question.

Answer (score 4):

If your page is in a specific file you can use the `<Files>` ... `</Files>` directive

```
<Files secret.php >
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Will deny access to the secret.php page